# How to use gnuplot to plot history graph with labels

Tags: gnuplot

I have two small datafiles

one

```
11  365.4
12  659.2
```

and one

```
11  432.1
12  882.4
```

I try to plot those as a histogram with labels

```
gnuplot <<EOF                                                                                               
                                                                                                            
set output 'house-energy.png'                                                                               
set terminal png size 800,400 font "Arial,10"                                                               
                                                                                                            
                                                                                                            
set boxwidth 0.7 relative                                                                                   
set grid ytics linestyle 0                                                                                  
set style fill solid 0.20 border                                                                            
                                                                                                            
set style data histogram                                                                                    
#set style histogram columnstacked                                                                          
#set style histogram rowstacked                                                                             
                                                                                                            
set title "Energy"                                                                                          
set xlabel "Month"                                                                                          
set ylabel "kWh"                                                                                            
set yrange [0:2000]                                                                                         
                                                                                                            
plot 'file1.dat' u 2: xtic(1) with histogram lc rgb "#0045FF" title "Energy house total", \     
     '' using 1:(\$2):(\$2) with labels notitle font ",10" , \                                              
     'file2.dat' u 2: xtic(1) with histogram lc rgb "#004500" title "Labb", \                          
     '' using 1:(\$2):(\$2) with labels notitle  font ",10"                                                 
                                                                                                            
EOF
```

But the labels are way off

[Image showing plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BwyI.png)

// GH

Answer (score 0):

The histogram plotting style is implicitly using the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`) as x-coordinate. So, you have to place your label at `column(0)` or `($0)` with some x-offset, e.g. `($0-0.15)` in the one and other direction. And some offset in y-direction, e.g. via `offset 0,0.7`.

**Script:**

```
### histogram with labels
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
11  365.4
12  659.2
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
11  432.1
12  882.4
EOD

set boxwidth 0.7 relative
set grid ytics linestyle 0
set style fill solid 0.20 border

set style data histogram
set title "Energy"
set xlabel "Month"
set ylabel "kWh"
set yrange [0:2000]
set key noautotitle

plot $Data1 u 2:xtic(1)     w histogram lc rgb "#0045FF" title "Energy house total", \
         '' u ($0-0.15):2:2 w labels font ",10" offset 0,0.7, \
     $Data2 u 2             w histogram lc rgb "#004500" title "Labb", \
         '' u ($0+0.15):2:2 w labels font ",10" offset 0,0.7
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Ok. Got it. Works nice.

Comment: @GHasse glad to hear. If it solved your problem, please check the check mark at the top left of the answer, indicating that your question is answered.